# Change character row value based on condition (NAs are not allowed in subscripted assingments)

Tags: r, paste

I have two columns.

Whenever the first column has the value `"Breast"` for a given row, I want to add the value of another column `(test$IHC)`.

This code should work fine:

```
testdat$Pathology[testdat$Pathology == "Breast"] <- paste("Breast (", testdat$IHC, ")")
```

The problem however is that the function `testdat$Pathology[testdat$Pathology == "Breast"]` includes NA in the vector, and this prompts an error when executing the function in the first row:

```
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

The problem I'm finding is that `na.omit()` doesn't work as I think it generates some modifications in the data:

```
na.omit(testdat$Pathology[testdat$Pathology == "Breast"]) <- paste("Breast (", testdat$IHC, ")")
```

Comment: `testdat$Pathology[! is.na(testdat$Pathology) & testdat$Pathology == "Breast"] <- paste(...)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may check for NA explicitly. Remember also to include the same filters on the right side, or the vectors won`t match and the values will be offset.

```
testdat$Pathology[! is.na(testdat$Pathology) & testdat$Pathology == "Breast"] <- paste0("Breast (", testdat$IHC[! is.na(testdat$Pathology) & testdat$Pathology == "Breast"], ")")
```

You may make it cleaner by saving the common expression in a variable:

```
subscripts.to.replace <- ! is.na(testdat$Pathology) & testdat$Pathology == "Breast"
testdat$Pathology[subscripts.to.replace] <- paste0("Breast (", testdat$IHC[subscripts.to.replace], ")")
```